# Axios response undefined although browsers network tab shows response

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I am using Laravel and Vue3 with axios to handle user inputs and save data to database.
If there is a validation error then I want to display a toast error to user.

For some reason the response from axios put function is undefined if Laravels validation fails.
I have tried all the other fixes I found on the net but am still getting undefined.

My axios instance:

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_BACKEND_URL,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        Accept: `application/json`,
    },
});
```

Function which calls Laravel (Api is the axios instance created above):

```
async confirmOrder(order: splicingPurchaseOrderType) {
   Api.put(`/splicing_purchase_orders/${order.id}`, {
      ...order,
   }).then((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);
   });
```

Function which gets called in Laravel:

```
public function put(SplicingPurchaseOrder $splicingPurchaseOrder, Request $request): JsonResponse
{
   $validated = $request->validate([
      'pallets' => 'required|numeric',
      'quality_id' => 'required|exists:App\Domain\Quality\Models\Quality,external_id',
      'specie_id' => 'required|exists:App\Domain\Specie\Models\Specie,external_id',
   ]);
```

And a screenshot of the actual response from browsers dev tools:
[Screenshot of dev tools network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7urG.png)

What am I missing?

I can just use if(!response) and display some generic error but that does not seem right and I have displayed Laravel validation errors just fine before. But at the moment I do not understand what is going on, should be a trivial task but I am failing.

I read that others have been mixing await and .then() together and that has caused the issue but that does not seem to be the issue I am facing. Tried const response = await Api.put...

Tried wrapping validate in try catch block in Laravel and write a return myself, still the same issue.

Must be a simple thing, I am just not seeing it.

Comment: what was wrong when you tried try catch block?

Comment: Still the same, on JavaScript side the code runs normally as long as I do not ask any response.status or stuff like that, because response is undefined. On Laravels side with or without try catch the behaviour is exactly the same. Laravel sends response but axios says that response is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios methods return a Promise that is resolved only when the response's status code is between 200-299 inclusive. For any other status code, the Promise would be rejected.

In your case, since the status code is 422, you can use either of these snippets to handle your error:

Using `async/await`:

```js
async confirmOrder(order: splicingPurchaseOrderType) {
  try {
    const res = await Api.put(`/splicing_purchase_orders/${order.id}`, {
      ...order,
    });
    console.log(res.data); // Success response
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data); // Error response
  }
}
```

Using `Promise.then/catch`:

```js
confirmOrder(order: splicingPurchaseOrderType) {
  Api.put(`/splicing_purchase_orders/${order.id}`, {
    ...order,
  })
    .then((res) => console.log(res.data)) // Success response
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.response.data)); // Error response
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but both of those functions got into then block and crash because "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')"

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, found the issue.

I had interceptor also in place, to handle the NProgress behaviour.

Interceptor on response looked like this:

```
instance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        callCount.value--;
        return response;
    },
    (error) => {
        callCount.value--;
    }
);
```

The error died there.
Added return to make the interceptor look like this:

```
instance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        callCount.value--;
        return response;
    },
    (error) => {
        callCount.value--;
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

Now I am getting the expected behaviour from Axios.